# Why apt wants to remove gnome-core when I try to remove gnome-terminal only?

Tags: gnome, apt, package-management

Why apt wants to remove gnome-core when I try to remove gnome-terminal only?

I am also wondering why apt is considering many packages useless?

I am using latest version of Kali Linux and it is based on Debian.

Here is the terminal output:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  baobab caribou caribou-antler empathy empathy-common fonts-cantarell gcalctool gdm3 gnome-backgrounds gnome-dictionary
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data gnome-screenshot
  gnome-system-log gucharmap libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libcaribou-gtk-module libcaribou-gtk3-module
  libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libgdict-1.0-6 libgdict-common libgdu-gtk0 libgeocode-glib0
  libtelepathy-farstream2 mobile-broadband-provider-info nautilus-sendto-empathy network-manager-gnome
  sound-theme-freedesktop telepathy-gabble telepathy-logger telepathy-salut vino
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-core gnome-terminal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
After this operation, 797 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gnome-core` is a meta-package and `gnome-terminal` is part of this package. It is no problem to remove the `gnome-core`-package.

And in your special case, reinstall automatically installed packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall baobab caribou caribou-antler empathy empathy-common fonts-cantarell gcalctool gdm3 gnome-backgrounds gnome-dictionary
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data gnome-screenshot
  gnome-system-log gucharmap libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libcaribou-gtk-module libcaribou-gtk3-module
  libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libgdict-1.0-6 libgdict-common libgdu-gtk0 libgeocode-glib0
  libtelepathy-farstream2 mobile-broadband-provider-info nautilus-sendto-empathy network-manager-gnome
  sound-theme-freedesktop telepathy-gabble telepathy-logger telepathy-salut vino
```

Comment: I have uninstalled the gnome-terminal. Now apt is saying that some packages are installed and no longer required and I feel that my desktop will break If I uninstall those packages. See those packages in my question.

Comment: Will my desktop break after removing those packages?

Comment: No, your desktop is not destroyed. These packages are also installed by the meta-package. Install it just once. `sudo apt-get reinstall baobab caribou caribou-antler empathy ...`

Comment: I have improved my answer.